# Constructor and object declaration specific matter

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, optimization, arduino

In my `main.cpp` file I call the constructor of a class. In the constructor I set the variables of this class from some static functions. All the problem is about setting time from an NTP server.

The static functions which are a getters use a `while` loop in order to check a flag. The flag is false if time is not set and true if at least one time the NTP server has responded. If the flag is false the `while` loop has to try to get time forever (because there is no reason to continue without time) and if it is true, it returns the time.

The constructor sets the variables as I said by calling the getters.

When I declare the object of that class in main, the program does not run because I get nothing on serial print. If I outcomment the declaration it works. Also, it does not act like stucking inside the `while` because I placed a serial print inside there, and it did not appear either. I give the code below:

The constructor:

```
#import "DayTime.h"
#include "NTP.h"

DayTime::DayTime(){
    hour = NTP::getLCThour();
    minutes = NTP::getMin();
    seconds = NTP::getSec();
}
```

The `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "NTP.h"
#include "DayTime.h"
#include "DayNumber.h"

DayTime DT;
DayNumber DN;

int main(void)
{
    init();
    setup();
    for (;;)
        loop();
    return 0;
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    NTP::startEthernetAndUdp();
}

void loop() {
    NTP::getTime();
    //    Serial.println(DT.hour);
    //    Serial.println(DT.getTimeToDec());
    delay(3000);
```

Here the getTime function works if I comment the declaration of the DayTime object named DT.

The NTP.cpp parts:

1) The first getter:

```
int NTP::getLCThour(){
    while(timeNTPSet==false){
        Serial.print("kolaw");
        getTime();
    }
    return lcthour;
}
```

2) The declaration of the flag on header:

```
static bool timeNTPSet;
```

This is a public variable.

3) Its definition at the start of the .cpp file:

```
bool NTP::timeNTPSet= false;
```

This is set in the .cpp file after the include.

And at last part of the function that sets the flag to true:

```
NTP NTP::getTime(){

    if (testNtpServer()){
        timeNTPSet = true;
        // We've received a packet, read the data from it
        Udp.read((unsigned char*)packetBuffer, NTP_PACKET_SIZE);
```

The testNTPServer function just tests 3-4 different NTP servers in order to get the time from at least from one. Also, it works fine if I comment the declaration of the DayTime object as I said before.

How can I do this?

Comment: :) inside getTime function that you see in main there are serial.prints. I get nothing if i do not comment the declaration. Also if i do not declare like this and i type inside the void loop: DayTime DT=DayTime();    it works.But i thought that the declaration runs the constructor

Answer (score 1):

You declare the `DayTime` variable to be a global variable. That means its constructor is called *before* your `main` function is called. And as the serial port, as well as the networking I'm guessing, is not set up then it will not work.

You could create an initialization in the `DayTime` class, that does what the constructor does, and call that after you set up the serial port and networking.

Comment: ok about this prob with serial port but at the loop() i have the function gettime that has nothing to do with the DayTime class. And it does not work and give its serial prints. Also DT object calls its constructor before but the serial print in loop() as you can see commented did not worked eather so i could read the variables.These are set in the loop so inside my main.